# How to connect inbuilt User database to another one in Django?

Tags: django, database

I am a beginner in Django. I have created a login, logout and register pages for my Django projects. When a user signs in I want them to only the posts that they have made. I am not sure how to make the users that I already have be able to login into their own pages and manage their budgets and etc.

[Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmFGP.png)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User# user authentication
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model#for connecting the inbuild user database

class List(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(User)
 item = models.CharField(max_length=200)#field to type the name of the budget
 completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)#this needs to be changed later

def __str__(self):
    return self.item + ' | ' + str(self.completed)
```

Comment: Have you tried as written here: [Multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#multiple-databases)

Answer (score 0):

Django contrib auth is a good way to handle basic user system https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/. Then you can use `request.user` when a user is logged in, filter a queryset in your view and and show them just their posts or lists `List.objects.filter(user=request.user)`

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.